# translate const delphi 7 gnugettext

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gettext

I have some constants such code below. I need translate them and i have tried with _() but don't work.
thanks in advance.

```
const system_name    = 'System Name';
  business_name    = 'Business Name';
```

Comment: i tried with:
http://dybdahl.dk/dxgettext/docs/beta/online/directives.html
but notting happen...

Comment: i did! http://dybdahl.dk/dxgettext/docs/beta/online/directives.html i had forgotten that my constants was on other project.

Comment: now my problem is with arrays:

Answer (score 2):

If I need to handle constants, that have to be translated, I usually declare them as `resourcestring`:

```
resourcestring 
  system_name = 'System Name';
  business_name = 'Business Name';
```

dxgettext handles these without any tweaking.